# How to create excel file in android ?

Tags: java, android, excel

I'm trying to create an excel file in android. But when I click the button to create the file, my app crashes.

**LogCat**

```
02-12 17:43:48.287: E/dalvikvm(25342): Could not find class 'jxl.WorkbookSettings', referenced from method lmf.test7.MainActivity.onClick
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl.WorkbookSettings
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at lmf.test7.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:44)
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-12 17:43:51.257: E/AndroidRuntime(25342):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        String Fnamexls="testfile"  + ".xls";

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/newfolder");
        directory.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(directory, Fnamexls);

        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

        WritableWorkbook workbook;
        try {
            int a = 1;
            workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
            WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
            Label label = new Label(0, 2, "SECOND");
            Label label1 = new Label(0,1,"first");
            Label label0 = new Label(0,0,"HEADING");
            Label label3 = new Label(1,0,"Heading2");
            Label label4 = new Label(1,1,String.valueOf(a));

            try {
                sheet.addCell(label);
                sheet.addCell(label1);
                sheet.addCell(label0);
                sheet.addCell(label4);
                sheet.addCell(label3);
            } catch (RowsExceededException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (WriteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            workbook.write();

            try {
                workbook.close();
            } catch (WriteException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Btw, I used Java Excel API.

Comment: It seems like `jxl.WorkbookSettings` not found. add `Java Excel API.jar` into project `libs` and clean and built your project

Comment: "Could not find class 'jxl.WorkbookSettings'"

Comment: @MD - how can I add it to libs folder? When I tried adding it to my project, my project creates a new folder named "Referenced Libraries" and add it there.

Comment: @speedsir you go wrong. create `libs` folder into your project and add this `.jar` file into it.

Comment: @speedsir or `goto right click project->goto properties -> goto libraries ->you see Add External JARS` button click on it and add

Comment: @MD - thank you sir. No errors. But I don't know why I can't see any "newfolder" folder in my sdcard. I guess I'll just ask another question about this problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `jxl.WorkbookSettings` not found. add **Java Excel API.jar** into project **libs** and clean and built your project.

Follow this steps to **add external library** or **JARS** into your project:

> right click project->goto properties ->click on "Java Build Path" located on left side-> goto libraries ->you see
>   Add External JARS button click on it and add.

Answer (score 2):

```
***use this code with jar file poi-3.7.jar***

import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button Excel;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Excel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Excel);
        Excel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveExcelFile("MyExcel.xls");
            }
        });
    }

    private static boolean saveExcelFile(String fileName) {
        String path;
        File dir;
        if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
            Log.e("Failed", "Storage not available or read only");
            return false;
        }
        boolean success = false;

        //New Workbook
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

        Cell c = null;

        //Cell style for header row
        CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
        cs.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
        cs.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cs.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

        CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);

        //New Sheet
        Sheet sheet1 = null;
        sheet1 = wb.createSheet("myOrder");

        // Generate column headings
        Row row = null;

        row = sheet1.createRow(0);

        c = row.createCell(0);
        c.setCellValue("Item Number");
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(1);
        c.setCellValue("Quantity");
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(2);
        c.setCellValue("Price");
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        sheet1.setColumnWidth(0, (15 * 500));
        sheet1.setColumnWidth(1, (15 * 500));
        sheet1.setColumnWidth(2, (15 * 500));

        int val = 0;
        int k = 1;
        for(int i=1;i<12;i++){
            row = sheet1.createRow(k);
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                c = row.createCell(j);
                c.setCellValue(val);
                c.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                val++;
            }
            sheet1.setColumnWidth(i, (15 * 500));
            k++;
        }

        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/EXCEL/";
        dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(dir, fileName);
        FileOutputStream os = null;

        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            wb.write(os);
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file);
            success = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (null != os)
                    os.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio you can do as follow:-

1. Create a folder "lib" in your app project
2. Copy jxl.jar and paste it in "lib" folder
3. Right Click on the jxl.jar. Select Add as Library
4. Finish

Now Clean and Run the project.